Opportunity Multi-Line Custom Filter Without Custom Code
The business would like either a toggle that can filter opportunity products, instead of using the quick filters. Or a button that uses predefined filters. As much as we are pushing back because this request really stems from them having this in their old system and Salesforce having Quick filters which do the same thing in one place in one click.
I have 0 desire to create a custom LWC multi-product select tool but I do have a suspicion that is exactly what they will request. I am just doing my due diligence as I do believe the answer is no.
thanks

Is the context the list view? What is wrong with selecting from "shared" filters?

I really don't understand to be honest. How it was explained to me was that it was not user friendly enough. Which could be translated as we have very  coddled users or a more cynical person may have a more harsh translation.   We have over 10k users, so we will placate.

Heard similar feedback from our customers on list views - they want a quick, one click way of switching filter criteria on/off. SF requires you to do this switch by changing the view. If they're paying for dev, give them a button to switch between two list views.

For Opportunity Multi-Product, I think that is a custom LWC, is that correct?
