List view restriction in Experience Cloud!
Have a use case where a user have access to two communities. She has requirement where when logins to Community one she only see list views which shows only that community specific cases and the same way if she logins to the other community, she sees only that community specific case list view.
Is there any way we can achieve this in the experience cloud?

Similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/421356/opportunity-multi-line-custom-filter-without-custom-code , see comments
